# AWS Managed Update Configuration not working

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-elastic-beanstalk

I created an environment in Elastic Beanstalk & configured managed updates for Every Monday.

But after configuration changes are applied, it still shows "No managed updates are scheduled for this environment."

Is there something else I need to set in EB configuration along with managed updates?